# Restore the bread crumb navigation in SP 2013 using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, breadcrumb

Is there a way to enable Restore the bread crumb navigation in SP 2013 using PowerShell? I saw multiple links, but didn't get any PS Script to do the same.

```
 var masterPage = this.Page.Master;
var delta = masterPage.FindControl("DeltaBreadcrumbDropdown") as AjaxDelta;
if (delta != null)
{
car breadcrumb = delta.FindControl("GlobalBreadCrumbNavPopout") as 
       PopoutMenu;
    if (breadcrumb != null)
    {
        breadcrumb.Visible = true;
        breadcrumb.ThemeKey = "spcommon";
        breadcrumb.IconUrl = "/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png";
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<style type="text/css">.ms-
        breadcrumb-dropdownBox { display: inline-block !important; }
         </script>"));
```

am looking for similar code in powershell, is this possible?